# Record time from now, to when a button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering how to record the time taken from running the method below, to when a UIButton is pressed -- could anyone possibly help?

```
-(void)informToPress
{
    textLabel.text = @"Test, press the button";
    //begin record and end record on button press
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)informToPress
{
    textLabel.text = @"Test, press the button";
    //begin record and end record on button press

    startDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)stopTime{
    stopDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

    //The actual time in seconds
   NSLog(@"Time in seconds %f", [stopDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]);
}
```

**OR**

```
-(IBAction)calculateTime{
        //The actual time in seconds just calculated not stored.
       NSLog(@"Time in seconds %f", [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
}
```

Comment: Time interval is a double i think, so wouldn't you want to put a %f instead of the %i?

Comment: Also, tried printing the time taken, to the textLabel with: "textLabel.text = @"Time it took %i", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer];" but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @buzzkip the label text setter doesn't implicitly format the string like the NSLog call does. You should do something like textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]];

Comment: @Zaky, thank you so much! This helpfulness on stackoverflow goes unmatched

Comment: Do you know how to use "textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]];" in a completely different .m file?

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do. A. if you want to get the time that was already calculated `"textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", classA.calculatedTime];` or B. if you want to calculate the time from another .m file. `"textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [classA.startTimer timeIntervalSinceNow]];`